# Golang Program to convert RGB and Hex to DMC colors

Tags: beginner, console, go

I wrote a small console app for converting RGB or Hex values (by specfying on top of the input file) to the nearest colour of DMC thread. I'm curious to know how I could improve my code organisation or if there are any best practices I could be following better. I know I have no tests and I'm uncertain of the best way to handle errors so I currently either dont or just panic...

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image/color"
    "math"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "parkeradam.dev/dmc-convert/dmc"
    "parkeradam.dev/dmc-convert/rgbcolor"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func readlines(path string) []string {
    data, err := os.ReadFile(path)
    check(err)
    str := string(data)
    content := strings.Split(strings.ReplaceAll(str, "\r\n", "\n"), "\n")
    return content
}

func getClosest(dmcCols []dmc.Dmc, col color.RGBA) (currentDmc dmc.Dmc) {

    var lowest = math.MaxInt32

    for _, item := range dmcCols {
        diff := rgbcolor.Compare(item.Color, col)
        debug := fmt.Sprintf("%+v , %d , %d", item, diff, lowest)
        fmt.Println(debug)
        if diff < lowest {
            lowest = diff
            currentDmc = item
        }
    }

    return currentDmc
}

func main() {
    dmcLines := readlines("./dmc_colors.csv")
    var dmcCols []dmc.Dmc

    for _, item := range dmcLines {
        dmcCols = append(dmcCols, dmc.FromCsvLine(item))
    }

    colorList := readlines("./colors.txt")
    colorType := strings.ToLower(colorList[0])
    colorsToConvert := colorList[1:]

    for _, item := range colorsToConvert {
        if colorType == "rgb" {
            color := rgbcolor.FromSpaceSepeartedLine(item)
            nearest := getClosest(dmcCols, color)
            fmt.Println(nearest)
        } else if colorType == "hex" {
            color, _ := rgbcolor.ParseHexColor(item)
            fmt.Println("Color", color)
            nearest := getClosest(dmcCols, color)
            fmt.Println(nearest)
        } else {
            panic("Unknown input type")
        }
    }
}
```

hexcolor.go (i know its in rgb package, I couldnt make a color package as that is taken)

```golang
package rgbcolor

import (
    "fmt"
    "image/color"
)

func HexFromRgbColor(color color.RGBA) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("#%X%X%X", color.R, color.G, color.B)
}

func ParseHexColor(s string) (c color.RGBA, err error) {
    c.A = 0xff
    switch len(s) {
    case 7:
        _, err = fmt.Sscanf(s, "#%02x%02x%02x", &c.R, &c.G, &c.B)
    case 4:
        _, err = fmt.Sscanf(s, "#%1x%1x%1x", &c.R, &c.G, &c.B)
        // Double the hex digits:
        c.R *= 17
        c.G *= 17
        c.B *= 17
    default:
        err = fmt.Errorf("invalid length, must be 7 or 4")

    }
    return
}
```

rgb.go

```golang
package rgbcolor

import (
    "image/color"
    "math"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func intAbs(num int) int { return int(math.Abs(float64(num))) }

func subtractHighestFromLowest(i1, i2 uint8) int {
    if i1 > i2 {
        return int(i1 - i2)
    }
    return int(i2 - i1)
}

func Compare(col1 color.RGBA, col2 color.RGBA) int {
    var diff int = subtractHighestFromLowest(col1.R, col2.R) +
        subtractHighestFromLowest(col1.G, col2.G) +
        subtractHighestFromLowest(col1.B, col2.B)

    return intAbs(diff)
}

func parseToUint8(str string) uint8 {
    value, _ := strconv.ParseUint(str, 10, 8)
    return uint8(value)
}

func FromSpaceSepeartedLine(str string) (col color.RGBA) {
    segments := strings.Split(str, " ")
    col.R = parseToUint8(segments[0])
    col.G = parseToUint8(segments[1])
    col.B = parseToUint8(segments[2])
    return
}
```

and finally dmc.go

````golang
package dmc

import (
    "image/color"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    "parkeradam.dev/dmc-convert/rgbcolor"
)

type Dmc struct {
    Floss int
    Name  string
    Color color.RGBA
    Hex   string
}

func trimAndConvertToUInt8(str string) uint8 {
    val, _ := strconv.ParseInt(strings.TrimSpace(str), 10, 0)
    return uint8(val)
}
func trimAndConvertToInt(str string) int {
    val, _ := strconv.ParseInt(strings.TrimSpace(str), 10, 0)
    return int(val)
}

func FromCsvLine(csvLine string) Dmc {
    items := strings.Split(csvLine, ",")
    dmc := Dmc{
        Floss: trimAndConvertToInt(items[0]),
        Name:  strings.TrimSpace(items[1]),
        Color: color.RGBA{
            R: trimAndConvertToUInt8(items[2]),
            G: trimAndConvertToUInt8(items[3]),
            B: trimAndConvertToUInt8(items[4]),
        },
    }
    dmc.Hex = rgbcolor.HexFromRgbColor(dmc.Color)
    return dmc
}
```
````